# Help deciphering this awk command

Tags: awk

I'm learning awk following a book, and I've been given this example with no real explanation of what's going on:

```
awk ' NR%2 {printf "%s,", $0; next;}1 ' < linepairs.csv
```

For context, linepairs.csv is a file containing lines of several csv values:

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

and so on...

This awk command is supposed to join lines together. I've been playing around with it, changing `NR%2` to `(NR%2==0)` thinking they were equivalent, but it gave me the opposite result. I understand how printf works, and I just learnt about 'next', but I'm not sure what's really doing there. Finally, the 1 at the end is really puzzling me, since it's not mentioned in the book before.

If anyone could translate that command for me, that'd really be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk programs consist of `pattern {action}` rules. The `{action}` is executed if the `pattern` evaluates TRUE. TRUE in awk is denoted by a *non*-zero value. Hence `NR%2` is equivalent to `NR%2 != 0`

One or other of `pattern {action}` may be omitted.

- if `pattern` is absent, then `{action}` is applied to every record
- if `{action}` is absent, then the default action is `{print}`

The pattern `1` is idiomatically used as an "always true" pattern in order to invoke the default `{print}` action for every record.

Rules are read from left to right. The `next` statement is used to skip past any remaining rules.

Hence `awk ' NR%2 {printf "%s,", $0; next;}1 ' < linepairs.csv` executes

- `printf "%s,", $0` if `NR%2` evaluates non-zero, skipping the pattern `1` and its default `{print}` action

and

- `{print}` otherwise

Comment: I know all the books say `pattern` but while that term made some sense for the original awk that came out in the 1970s due what functionality awk had at that time, it no longer makes sense. `condition` is a far more clear and accurate term than `pattern` for what goes in that part of an awk script.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now. The explanation about non-zero values evaluating TRUE and the role of the 1 made me get it. I really had that thing backwards.